# Gitlab block merge requests from feature into master

Tags: gitlab

Is there a way to block creating/approving merge requests from **"feature/*"** branches into master?
I need to allow only merge requests from **"release/*"** and **"hotfix/*"** branches.

When creating MergeRequest via GUI the default target branch is master. So human error while doing this may break a workflow and merge untested\unbuild feature into master.

Our current workflow is coding new features in **"feature/*"** branches. Merging several features into new **"release/*"** branch and CI makes a build and tests of this release. After testing this release goes on the prod server and into **master**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since GitLab permissions are role-based, there's no way to set permissions per branch (other than setting a branch as protected in `Settings / Repository / Protected Branches`, which which controls *who* can merge not *which branch* can merge ). However, you could do the following:

1. In your GitLab CICD (if you don't have it set up already I highly recommend, its a handy tool) set up a check that runs always to determine which branch is trying to be merged ($CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME is what you want, [see all GitLab default environment variables here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)) and if the branch name matches 'feature/*', then have the pipeline fail
2. Under `Settings / General / Merge Requests`, under `Merge Checks`, check the option `Pipelines must succeed`.

Now, if someone attempts to create a Merge Request from a feature branch, the pipeline will fail and no one will be allowed to approve the Merge Request.